# Blender stops receiveing some keyboard & mouse input after TouchEgg actions

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, blender, touchegg

Sometimes the keyboard & mouse stop working correctly in Blender and I have to press the Alt key twice (to open and close Ubuntu HUD), or press the Super key twice (to open and close Unity Dash) or press Alt+Tab once (to select Blender window, even though it already looks selected).

It happens after some time almost every time I'm editing videos, but looks like random behavior. There is, though, one thing that reproduces the bug every time: I have TouchEgg installed, and every time I use the laptop's touchpad to change from one workspace to another, Blender stops receiving keyboard & mouse inputs (except for clicking on buttons like 'File', 'Window', 'Help').

I've reported as a bug, but the developer tested and said he couldn't reproduce it, so it was not considered a bug, even though only Blender presents the problem.

Now I need help to find what the problem is and I don't have a clue where to start looking.

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit Unity
Dell Laptop with multi-touch touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else experiencing this : you can try changing the shortcut for switching between keyboard layouts, or disabling it altogether. 
To do this : go to **System settings** → **Text entry**, and change the shortcut for "Switch to next using" to something else. Disabling it is done by pressing Backspace.

I had a similar issue to what OP is describing and it was driving me crazy. Turns out I had the shortcut set to both Shift keys, which for some strange reason made Blender think I was pressing the Alt key sometimes while I wasn't. I also tested other desktop environments, and it seems that Unity is the only one where this happens.

This may or may not work in OP's case, but it's worth giving a it try. If the issue still persists then I suggest booting from a live CD and testing if the problem is there. This would confirm if it's something related to your hardware, or simply some third party program interfering with Blender.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, but may help other people.
What if there's another shortcut conflict? Do you know where to look?