# Why is the "start" menu being opened when I do two Super+w actions through touchegg configured finger swipes?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, synaptics, touchegg

I have touchegg configured so that up or down three finger swipes triggers Super+w:

```
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="UP">
<action type="SEND_KEYS">Super+w</action>
</gesture>
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="DOWN">
<action type="SEND_KEYS">Super+w</action>
</gesture>
```

When I do two three finger swipes either up or down in a row, the second one causes the "start" menu to be opened (as if I pressed the super key alone). This doesn't happen when I do Super+w twice in a row from my keyboard. I'd like to know why that might be happening so that I can fix it. My system is a Dell XPS 13 9350 with synaptics touchpad. Thanks.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue that I have posted here:
[Blender stops receiveing some keyboard & mouse input after TouchEgg actions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886345/blender-stops-receiveing-some-keyboard-mouse-input-after-touchegg-actions)

I think touchegg may have some issues releasing the key combination on time and somehow the software keeps the last key pressed or something like that. Still trying to figure that out.

But I'm losing hope... So maybe the solution for both of us is to change the software we use for multitouch gestures. I'm going for **Ginn**, but there are some others you may want to take a look at.

Hope I've helped you.